# GP Fill Tool Doesn't Work in non 2D animation set up. How to get it to work in 3D space?

Tags: grease-pencil

I want to add a GP object to my 3D scene, so I'm making it in the scene because I needed it to align with my object (currently hidden) and the line work went fine.

But trying to fill the lines the fill seems to be going every which way and not just filling in my strokes like it would if it were 2D.

Is it not possible to do this? My linework isn't aligned to a specific axis, so I can't  work with it in the 2D animation tab.

Is it impossible to fill the linework?

[image: The purple blob is supposed to be the fill which is supposed to align with the ears]
[image: its random]